# Mysterious Whitespace with Stringbuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm writing a little calculator application and use a simple tokenizer to parse the user input into a list for subsequent processing.

The method looks like this:

```
public LinkedList<String> tokenize(String infix) throws Exception 
{
    LinkedList<String> tokens = new LinkedList<String>();
    StringBuilder operand = new StringBuilder("");

    char current;

    int index = 0;
    while(index <= infix.length() -1) {
        current = infix.charAt(index);

        if(!isOperator(current)) {
            operand.append(current);
        } else {
            // Add the operand stack
            tokens.add(operand.toString());
            operand = new StringBuilder("");
            // Add the operator
            tokens.add(Character.toString(current));
        }
        index++;
    }
    // The trailing operator
    tokens.add(operand.toString());
    return tokens;
}
```

The test I've set up for this method, looks like this:

```
public void testTokenizer() throws Exception 
{   
    LinkedList<String> list = parser.tokenize("35+35");
    assertTrue(list.get(0) == "35" &&
        list.get(1) == "+"  &&
        list.get(2) == "35");
}
```

However, this fails because the tokenizer seems to add whitespace to the tokens. For example, printing the list tokenized from the string "35+35" gives me:

```
[35, +, 35]
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Also be aware that the string comparisons are wrong, you must not use `==` for testing equality, use `equals()`. For instance: `"35".equals(list.get(0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the way how the String representation of the `List` is created during the call to `List#toString`. This is basically implemented as

```
firstElement + ", " + secondElement + ", " + ....
```

So these whitespaces are not in the *elements*, but only in the String representation of the List itself.

EDIT: You may also verify this by printing something like

```
System.out.println(">"+list.get(1)+"<");
```

This will print

```
>+<
```

and not

```
> +<
```

Answer (score 0):

The tokenizer is not adding space to the tokens. It is most likely being done by the [LinkedList's `toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) method when you display the list:

> The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets (`"[]"`). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters `", "` (comma and space).

The assertion doesn't work because it uses `==`. E.g., `list.get(0) == "35"` should be `list.get(0).equals("35")`. These are run-time String objects rather than compile time constants, so `==` won't do you want for comparisons.

Comment: Damn. I should have caught that one! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your test fails because it's comparing strings improperly.

If you change it to use the `.equals` method as you should, this test passes.

```
@Test
public void testTokenizer() throws Exception
{
    LinkedList<String> list = parser.tokenize("35+35");
    assertTrue(list.get(0).equals("35")
            && list.get(1).equals("+")
            && list.get(2).equals("35"));
}
```

The tokenizer is not adding whitespace.